# Get the correct mouse position of the image in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

What am I doing here is splitting the image based on the line.

This is the screenshot of my application:

[image]

This is my XAML code

```xaml
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="Gray">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding Imagesource, Source={x:Static vm:ListImagesVM.instance}}" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListLine, Source={x:Static vm:CropperVM.instance}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="Transparent"  
                      Width="{Binding ElementName=img, Path=ActualWidth}"
                      Height="{Binding ElementName=img,Path=ActualHeight}" 
                      LayoutTransform="{Binding ElementName=img, Path=LayoutTransform}">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDown">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MouseDownEvent" 
                                  TargetObject="{Binding Source={x:Static vm:CropperVM.instance}}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>   
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Line X1="{Binding X1}" Y1="{Binding Y1}" X2="{Binding X2}" 
                      Y2="{Binding ElementName=img, Path=ActualWidth}" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3"></Line>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

this is how i get the position

```
public void MouseDownEvent(object s, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (s == null) return;
        var canvas = s as Canvas;
        if (canvas == null) return;


        currentPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);

        Console.WriteLine("Position: " + currentPoint.X);


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

The coordinates of the line is `1175` but the image itself is `7424`.
I cut the image in half. How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Why does the position of the line is only `1175` when i put the line in the half of the image?

Comment: *"I cut the image in half. How can I solve this problem?"* What exactly **is** the problem? Can you turn it into a [mcve]?

Comment: sorry about that. I updated my question. Why does the position of the line is only `1175` when i put the line in the half of the image?

Comment: Probably because you don't show the image in native resolution. The `Image` control by default stretches the image to fit the space it has available. When you set `Stretch=None` it might work but would be to big for the screen. Since this issue is quite broad - on what part specifically are you looking for help? Would an example on how to get the pixel position of a stretched image in code-behind help?

Comment: i already tried it but the position is still the same

Comment: Have you also tried getting the position from the image instead of the canvas (`currentPoint = e.GetPosition(img);`)? Depending on any Transformations applied during the layouting it might not be the same. Another thing to keep in mind with WPF is, that it is DPI-aware (default size at 96 I think) so some images might display bigger/smaller than they actually are (There is also a windows setting that scales applications by 100, 125 or 150% that can mess with that). Long story short - an image pixel will not always be a screen pixel.

Comment: so if that is the case. How can i solve it sir? what formula do i need? can you share. i tried the position * screen dpi / image resolution. but it won't work. the coordinates are still wrong and the output

Comment: @bobpalok See if the ratio between the Imagesource's Width and PixelWidth (or Height and PixelHeight) can help.

Comment: what do you mean by ratio @Clemens.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ratio